# Meteor: Youtube videos don't show on iOS and Android in production

Tags: cordova, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, meteor-react

In my meteor-react app I have embedded some YouTube videos. These work fine on all devices in debug mode but in production (where I can't use Chrome Inspect to debug it) the videos just don't show up on mobile devices. In the browser it always works perfectly.

In my implementation I first used a simple iframe to embed the video. This didn't work so I tried using the react-youtube package, which accesses the videos via the Youtube-API. This yielded the exact same behavior.

How can I fix this?

It might be a CORS error but adding

```
App.accessRule('youtube.com');
App.accessRule('http://*');
App.accessRule('https://*');
```

to my mobile-config.js did not help. I then tried adding the `browser-policy` package to my project and fixing all the errors it threw in the browser by adding

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("www.youtube.com"); //the www. was important
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("s.ytimg.com");
BrowserPolicy.content.allowMediaDataUrl();
```

to the Meteor.startup() function but this also had no results on mobile platforms.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Not really. I used another plugin called "react-player" and it worked...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using another plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170489/how-to-play-youtube-videos-inside-meteor-in-cordova/44460295#44460295

Answer (score 0):

You must allow specific access to resources outside your server's URL.

Add the following rule in your `mobile-config.js` file (this file should be in your root project directory):

`App.accessRule('youtube.com');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it does not work. I added
`App.accessRule('youtube.com');`
and after that didn't work I also added `'http://*'` and `'https://*'` as rules which also had no effect.

Comment: I see.  Well, if the problem is only on iOS devices, check if you are not calling a http site for youtube from your server, being it a secure site (htpps).  iOS will block connections to non secure sites.   When you say it doesn't work, is the player preview window showing on mobile?

Comment: The problem also occurs on Android devices (in fact I can only debug it there but have heard the issue also occurs on iOS). The player preview is not showing, in fact there is nothing rendering at all. Only thing that can be seen is that other HTML render below the space where the player would be. From this I conclude that the iframe is being created with the specified dimensions, but the page inside that frame is not being loaded.

Comment: I checked the plugin site and I couldn't find any issues reported regarding the display in mobile devices on production.  I don't know where do you have hosted your production server, but can you check if the plugin is properly deployed to it?  I'm falling short on ideas...